# Regex with numerics and dashes only

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I am facing an issue in JavaScript form validation. I have to store number in this format 1-74347064527
 I have tried these regular expressions but not worked properly:

```
var srNo =/^[-0-9]*$/;
var srNo = /^[0-9]+(-[0-9]+)+$/; 
var srNo=/^([0-9]+-)*[0-9]+$/;
```

Suggest some regex for this. 
Kind regards.

Comment: What's wrong with `^[0-9]+-[0-9]+$` or `^\d+-\d+$` ?

Comment: @hwnd you mean this var srNo=/^\d+-\d+/; Right ? Its not working !

Comment: It may help if you could provide more examples or attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>When in a character class (`[ ]`), dash ( `-` ) has a special meaning in regular expressions - it means "range", eg. `a-z` means `from 'a' to 'z'`. You're not escaping it, so your RegExps are not even correct (at least not in every language).</s>

**Update:** It appears, that this syntax is correct when dash is not surrounded by other characters (when it's placed at the beginning or end of the character class). Sorry for confusion.

Try this instead:

```
/^\d\-\d+$/
```

It matches strings that begin with one digit, followed by a dash, and then by one or more digits.

Answer (score 1):

This should work unless you have additional constraints:

```
var srNo = /^\d+-\d+$/;
```

If you prefer the `[0-9]` syntax:

```
var srNo = /^[0-9]+-[0-9]+$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var regex = /^\d{1}-?\d{11}$/g
window.alert(regex.test('1-74347064527'));
```